# Is it possible to close a Reader without closing the stream?

Tags: java, inputstream, resource-leak

I have a method which accepts an `InputStream` (of binary data) and serializes it to XML.  In order to do so, it wraps the stream with a base64 encoder and a `Reader` to convert it to character data.  However, since the `InputStream` is passed in as a parameter, I would consider it a harmful side effect to close the stream, and the contract for `Reader.close()` says it would do just that.  If I don't close the reader, the compiler warns me that I have a

> Resource leak: reader is never closed

So, I can add a `@SuppressWarnings( "resource" )` to the reader declaration, but is that the right thing to do?  Am I missing something?

Here is the actual code:

```
/**
 * Writes base64 encoded text read from the binary stream.
 * 
 * @param binaryStream
 *            The binary stream to write from
 * @return <code>this</code> XmlWriter (for chaining)
 * @throws IOException
 */
public XmlWriter binary( InputStream binaryStream ) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( 
            new Base64InputStream( binaryStream, true, base64LineLength, base64LineSeparator.getBytes( charset ) ) );
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int charsRead;
    char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    while ( (charsRead = reader.read( buffer, 0, bufferSize )) >= 0 ) {
        writer.write( buffer, 0, charsRead );
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: What's your purpose for wanting to keep the Stream open? You could just re-open it at any time.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any way you can change your code to create one Reader for the InputStream, and pass that to methods that need a Reader? One way or another, the Reader and the input stream should be closed together.

Comment: @mabako, its not really a desire to keep the stream open, its more of a responsibility thing.  I try to close everything where it is opened.  If the binary method closes the stream and something outside of this call tries to do something with it, it could through an exception that the user didn't expect.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Good suggestion except that the thing that calls this does not think of the data as character data, so it wouldn't know to pass a Reader.  This method itself is used to convert binary data in to character data so it would be unreasonable to force the consumer of this library to do so before calling this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a happy Java 7 user, try this:

```
try(InputStream binaryStream = /* ... */) {
    xmlWriter.binary(binaryStream);
}
```

and stream is closed for you. If you can't use Java 7, I agree that it's not the responsibility of `binary()` method to `close()` the stream. Just ignore the warning and don't let tools drive your design. It's fine.

As a last resort you can write a lightweight `Reader` wrapper ignoring `close()`, but I don't advice it as it makes following the program flow harder.

Also let [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) help you with [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.Reader,%20java.io.Writer%29):

```
public XmlWriter binary( InputStream binaryStream ) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( 
            new Base64InputStream( binaryStream, true, base64LineLength, base64LineSeparator.getBytes( charset ) ) );
    IOUtils.copy(reader, writer);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your first segment as that just shows what i currently do, which is to say, close the `InputStream` in the caller of the binary method, not in the method itself.  I use java 6, but just have the close in a finally block.  I could write a wrapper, yes, but that seems less correct than the `@SuppressWarnings( "resource" )`.  Good suggestion on IOUtils, i usually do stuff like that, just that this is a low level library and i wanted as few dependencies as possible.

Comment: @Lucas: you are right, first part of my answer just reiterates your approach - which I found correct. Note that library `IOUtils.copy()` also does not close the `Reader` after copying it. I just want to say: it's the tool that is wrong, not you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perhaps a "feature" in the way [Base64InputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.java) work that even though you specify the length to read, it will close the underlying stream if you close it when clearly you intended not to read the whole stream.

You could wrap the binaryStream in an InputStream which ignores the close, or you could suppress the warning as you have.

Comment: Good suggestion on the wrapper, but that seems less correct than the `@SuppressWarnings( "resource" )`.